# Making different optimized versions of a website which can be access under one domain

Tags: html, css

I have tried to look this up to see if anyone has done this before but have not been getting any results. Is there a way to make a html+css website that can switch its layout, looks, and overall performance usage based on a computers operating system or browser. For example, a user on Windows 11 can still enjoy the latest iteration of my website while someone on an older OS, while might not be able to run the site to its fullest potential, will have the option to run the website on a basic layout while not losing functionality. I know websites are possible of changing its layout based on if the user is on a smart-device or desktop.

I have tried to do research with w3schools.

Comment: I believe you are referring to [responsive design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) (or at least a superset of it).

Answer (score -1):

Only using html + css it is impossible, if you use js it is possible to make a website that can switch its layout, looks, and overall performance based on a computer's operating system or browser. This technique is known as "browser sniffing" or "user agent sniffing".

You can use JavaScript or server-side code to detect the user's operating system and browser and then apply different stylesheets or scripts accordingly. However, this technique has some drawbacks, such as not always detecting the correct user agent or causing compatibility issues with new or unknown user agents.

A better approach would be to use a responsive web design that adapts to different screen sizes and resolutions, regardless of the operating system or browser. This will ensure that your website looks great and functions well on any device, without having to worry about the specific user agent.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1